# Strange wraping when rotating Bitmaps

Tags: java, matrix, rotation, transform, pixel

I started developing a custom Image class for a game which consists of three basic fields, width, height and a unidimensional array of int's which represent the color in the following order ARGB.

About two days ago i started trying to rotate images, and i was able to do that by converting this to a BufferedImage, rotate using Graphics2D and transforming it back to my own Image class, however setRGB and getRGB seem to be too slow and when i have to rotate about 10-20 images of 64*64 pixels the computer starts to struggle to maintain the fps.

So naturally i started developing my own image rotation function and i found a great post on gamedev.stackexchange.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67613/how-can-i-rotate-a-bitmap-without-d3d-or-opengl

The answer explains clearly what i should do to rotate an image even with different rotation points (which i intend to implement later).

However when following a similar formula to the one he explained (I had to change due to using a different coordinate system)
i find myself getting a strange wrapping at the top

Example (55 degrees): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmMCU.png (The Black area represents the image size)

So i tried to distanciate the image from the top, and added

```
yDstPixel += this.height*sin;
```

Which sorta worked, but now the image gets clipped in half instead of wrapped

Example (35 degrees):https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us3xT.png

I'm almost sure the solution is very simple, but i cant seem to figure it out, a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
public Bitmap getRotatedCopy(double radians){
    if(radians==0 || radians==(2*Math.PI)) return this;

    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians));
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));

    int newWidth  = (int) (this.width * cos + this.height * sin);
    int newHeight = (int) (this.width * sin + this.height * cos);

    Bitmap returnMap = new Bitmap(newWidth,newHeight); //set size of the returned bitmap to the smallest size possible
    returnMap.fill(0xFF000000);
    for (int y = 0; y < this.height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < this.width; x++){


            int srcPixel = x + (y * this.width);
            int color= this.pixels[srcPixel];
            if(color>0) continue;

            int xDstPixel = (int) Math.abs((x * cos + y * sin));
            int yDstPixel = (int) Math.abs((x * sin - y * cos));

            //yDstPixel += this.height*sin;

            int dstPixel = xDstPixel + (yDstPixel * newWidth);

            returnMap.pixels[dstPixel]=color;
        }
    }

    return returnMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to implement what you were planning to do later i.e. set the rotation origin and translation after the rotation.

I have modified your code to add them. (I didn't test running it but hope it works.)  Please refer to the code below:

```
int newWidth  = (int) (this.width * cos + this.height * sin);
int newHeight = (int) (this.width * sin + this.height * cos);

// After setting the new width and height...

// set rotation origin
double rox = this.width/2;
double roy = this.height/2;

// set translation center
double tcx = newWidth/2;
double tcy = newHeight/2;

Bitmap returnMap = new Bitmap(newWidth,newHeight);
returnMap.fill(0xFF000000);
for (int y = 0; y < this.height; y++){

    double yy = y - roy;

    for(int x = 0; x < this.width; x++){

        double xx = x - rox;

        int srcPixel = x + (y * this.width);
        int color= this.pixels[srcPixel];
        if(color>0) continue;

        // following two lines are modified
        int xDstPixel = (int) (xx * cos + yy * sin) + tcx;
        int yDstPixel = (int) (xx * sin - yy * cos) + tcy;

        // prevent negative index : maybe it is not needed at all
        if (xDstPixel<0 || yDstPixel<0)
            continue;

        int dstPixel = xDstPixel + (yDstPixel * newWidth);

        returnMap.pixels[dstPixel]=color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked after i added one to the newWidth and newHeight with your code.